# Why does sbt report "not found: value PlayScala" with Build.scala while build.sbt works?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am creating a multi-module sbt project, with following structure:

```
<root>
----build.sbt
----project
    ----Build.scala
    ----plugins.sbt
----common
----LoggingModule
```

`LoggingModule` is a Play Framework project, while `common` is a simple Scala project.

In `plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.3")
```

While I have this in `build.sbt`, all works fine and it recognises `PlayScala`:

```
name := "Multi-Build"

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(common, LoggingModule).dependsOn(common, LoggingModule)

lazy val common = project in file("common")

lazy val LoggingModule = (project in file("LoggingModule")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

However as soon I put this in `project/Build.scala` instead of `build.sbt' as follows:

```
object RootBuild extends Build {  

  lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
    .aggregate(common, LoggingModule)
    .dependsOn(common, LoggingModule)

  lazy val common = project in file("common")
  lazy val LoggingModule = (project in file("LoggingModule")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

  ...//other settings
}
```

it generates error as:

```
not found: value PlayScala
lazy val LoggingModule = (project in file("LoggingModule")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                                                                          ^
```

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just a missing import.

In `.sbt` files, some things are automatically imported by default: contents of objects extending `Plugin`, and (>= 0.13.5) `autoImport` fields in `AutoPlugin`s. This is the case of `PlayScala`.

In a `Build.scala` file, normal Scala import rules apply. So you have to import things a bit more explicitly. In this case, you need to `import play.PlayScala` (or use `.enabledPlugins(play.PlayScala)` directly).

Comment: With Play 2.5.x, the import is now `play.sbt.PlayScala`