# An undefined variable used by `enablePlugins` method?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-plugin

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)


name := "slick"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc4",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4"
)
```

And the `project/plugins.sbt` looks like this:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.6")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")
```

In the first line of my `build.sbt`, I saw codes like this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

What I can't understand is the `PlayScala`, which should be an undefined variable. But when I use sbt to build the project, sbt didn't complain about this. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sbt report "not found: value PlayScala" with Build.scala while build.sbt works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134083/why-does-sbt-report-not-found-value-playscala-with-build-scala-while-build-sb)

Comment: @DanielOlszewski I don't think this is a duplicate question. If I understand correctly, OP is asking how `PlayScala` was imported in the first place in build.sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I can't understand is the `PlayScala`, which should be an undefined variable.

See [Controlling the import with autoImport](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html#Controlling+the+import+with+autoImport).

> When an auto plugin provides a stable field such as val or object named autoImport, the contents of the field are wildcard imported in set, eval, and .sbt files.